Unable to run a ABP.io Template based Blazor-Server App with Version 8.2.3
i have created as small Blazor-Server app based on the ABP / VOLOSOFT Template. The Soulution was created with the abp-cli and the framework V8.2.3 and dotnet 8 is used.
I coded with VsCode and all works fine in Debugger, or the App is started with dotnet run xxx.csproj.
Now i try to publish this app. an use the dotnet publish command to build the release. this works also without exceptions. But when i try to run the app by "dotnet xxx.blazor.dll" in the publish directory nothing happens. No Error Message, the app simply does not start. and the cli returns to the prompt after 1s.
In older versions the command will start the app with kestrel and asp.net default settings.
Has anybody the same problem? Miss i something ?
How i can bring it to work ?
I have try different environments Windows and MacOs with same result.
Pls help to stop pulling out my hairs.
Bests enny
